# How to use Telerik RadGrid FilterExpression on DataTable programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, telerik

I have 2 pages 1 with Telerik RadGrid another with Telerik RadChart thay use the same DataTable. When I filtered RadGrid on the page I want to press the button and have the RadChart update to use the same filtered DataTable.

So first of all, here's what I've already tried.

With LINQ expressions turned off(`EnableLinqExpressions="false"`), I can set the RadGrid filter expression (for example) as follows:

```
Grid.MasterTableView.FilterExpression = "([Date] LIKE '%21%')"
```

And now I can use:

```
private void SetFiltring(ref DataTable table)
{
    table = table.Select("([Date] LIKE '%21%')", "").CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Its work great.

Now if I want to use LINQ expressions turned on(`EnableLinqExpressions="true"`)
I can set the RadGrid filter expression (for example) as follows:

```
Grid.MasterTableView.FilterExpression = "it["Date"].ToString().ToUpper().Contains("21".ToUpper()))"
```

And now i dont know how to use this FilterExpression on DataTable . How can  use this FilterExpression on DataTable.And Will Linq be faster than MSSQL Server syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problam was in .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 .for use Dynamic expressions i have to use
`using System.Linq;` and `using System.Linq.Dynamic;` 
and than i can use Linq:

```
private void SetFiltring(ref DataTable table)
{
    table = table.AsEnumerable()
                 .AsQueryable()
                 .Where("it["Date"].ToString().ToUpper().Contains("21".ToUpper()))")
                 .CopyToDataTable();
}
```

and now it will work

Comment: You can download System.Linq.Dynamic (.NET 4.0) from NuGet by searching for 'System.Linq.Dynamic'

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to do it the same way you are applying a filter above, check out this blog post:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aconrad/archive/2007/09/07/science-project.aspx

In it he gives a codebase to use a linq expression and then a method to turn it into a datatable.

Then it's a matter of assigning your grid's datasource to the datatable.